# mariaDB fulltext search in innoDB/XtraDB

Tags: full-text-search, mariadb

i have problem with full text search in innoDB/XtraDB engine.
i have full text on a column, some value is 1 or 2 length for example 'a' or 'aa'. 
i set ft_min_word_Len=1 and show variable show me that this variable set to 1. but when i query like this i get no result :

```
SELECT * FROM test.t1 t where match(text) against('aa' );
```

but when i change table engine to aria or myisam i get result.
what is the problem ?
i want to use innodb/Xtradb , not aria.

please help me.

Comment: [This page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/optimization-and-tuning/optimization-and-indexes/full-text-indexes/fulltext-index-overview/) states that fulltext search is available to InnoDb tables since MariaDB 10.0.5. Do/did you use an older version of MariaDB?

Answer (score 1):

You should change `innodb_ft_min_token_size` to 1. The setting `ft_min_word_Len` refers to myisam tables. See "Excluded Results" section on [this page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/fulltext-index-overview/) of the mariaDB knowledge base site.

Also see [this review](https://mariadb.com/blog/initial-impressions-innodb-fulltext) of the innodb full text search feature:

> ...I was a bit surprised to see that the default minimum word length was less than the value of ft_min_word_len. Those legacy ft_% variables continue to apply only to MyISAM fulltext indexes, evidently. There's a new bundle of system variables to control InnoDB Fulltext...